# Mitigate the lack of open generics in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

I would like to define an abstract base class

```
interface IMap<TItem> {
    [name: string]: TItem;
}

type Func<TParam, TResult> = (parameter: TParam) => TResult;

abstract class ItemBase<TItem> {
    items: IMap<TItem[]>;
    getItemKey: IMap<Func<TItem, number>>;

    itemsOn: IMap<number[]>; // stores enabled item IDs
    getItemOn: IMap<Func<TItem, boolean>>;

    abstract populate(): void;
}
```

I would like to store groups if similar but different items along with ID getter functions of each group so I can easily enumerate over these groups displaying their IDs.

Now in child classes that would extend this base class I would like to define a specific object map type i.e.

```
interface IFriendsMap<TItem> extends IMap<TItem> {
    male: TItem;
    female: TItem;
}

class Ancestors extends ItemBase<Person> {
    populate(): void {
        // populate data
    }
    ...
}
```

I would now like to access my type's properties with property accessor operator instead of using array notation:

```
let a = new Ancestors();

// I want these
a.items.male[0..n]
a.getItemKey.male(...)
a.itemsOn.male[0..n]
a.getItemOn.male(...)
// not this
a.items['male'][0..n]
a.getItemKey['male'](...)
a.itemsOn['male'][0..n]
a.getItemOn['male'](...)
```

As I have many different `IMap<>` properties in my base class it would be ideal to provide an open generic type as generic type parameter to `ItemBase` class like

```
class ItemBase<TItem, TMap<> extends IMap<>> {
    items: TMap<TItem[]>;
    ...
}
```

so this way I could easily pass in my custom object map type and property accessor (s|w)ould work:

```
class Ancestors extends ItemBase<Person, IFriendsMap<>> {
    ...
}
```

Another possibility would be if we could have partials. so that child classes would extend the original `IMap<T>` class.

### Question

A class can have several properties that will conform to the same object map having same properties (`IFriendsMap<T>` with properties being of different types of `T`). Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace your `IMap` with interfaces listing the exact properties you expect? Would get rid of a lot of complexity

Comment: @ÉdesBalázs: I can't because they're up to implementers of child classes...

Comment: `interface IMap<TItem> { (name: string): TItem; }` should that be `interface IMap<TItem> { [name: string]: TItem; }` ?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker is there a difference?

Comment: Yes. Parenthesis would declare a function type taking `name` parameter. Square brackets declares string indexer on an object.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker I'm a bit confused. Function of what name? Just some whatever function that would match this parameter and return type?

Comment: The way you wrote it is identical to `type IMap<TItem> = (name: string) => TItem;` It declares a function type. Judging from your example code it looks like you intended to declare an object type with an indexer for looking up properties by name: `obj["blah"]`

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Of course. That was my mistake of not knowing I've written it wrong. I want to have an object with properties of the same type and not functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want:

```
abstract class ItemBase<TItem, TSpecific> {
    items: IMap<TItem[]> & TSpecific;
    getItemKey: IMap<Func<TItem, number>>;

    itemsOn: IMap<number[]>; // stores enabled item IDs
    getItemOn: IMap<Func<TItem, boolean>>;

    abstract populate(): void;
}
```

That is, the `items` property must conform to both `IMap<TItem[]>` and `TSpecific`, whatever that is. Then suppose you said:

```
class Ancestors extends ItemBase<Person, IFriendsMap<Person>> {
    populate(): void {
        // populate data
    }
}
```

That way, you're saying that `items` is both an object with properties of type `Person` and also is a `IFriendsMap<Person>`. Hence:

```
let a = new Ancestors();

// This works
a.items.male
// This also works
a.items['male']
```

Comment: That's quite plausible, but you've only solved `items` property. There are the other three (`getItemKey`, `itemsOn` and `getItemOn`) that would use the same mapping. But there may be others too...

Comment: Can you see how to apply the same approach to those cases?

Comment: By adding as many generic type parameters as there are different usages of `IMap<T>`? I don't find that solution. We wouldn't even need intersection types to use the same technique would we? Ad in your code it  should actually be `IFriendsMap<Person[]>` so an array as generic parameter.

Comment: Of course the type parameter can be whatever you need. Intersection is the language feature you need to provide multiple ways of accessing the same object. Feel free to suggest how you'd achieve it otherwise, I'll be interested.

Comment: I was saying that instead of using intersection you could use inheritance to the same effect. I don't see any specific difference. In both cases one needs to provide all those different `IMap<Whatever>` types as generic type parameters. And that's rather cumbersome and prone to errors as well as hard to understand what exactly each of these types are. At least to the implementers of child classes.

Comment: As much as I don't like this solution I don't think there's any other way of accomplishing for the same. Thanks. I've reduced the amount of generic type parameters to limit only to publicly accessible class members. All of the others I've kept as object index.

Comment: Daniel, would you suggest a new way of doing this, since the language has evolved quite a bit in the last few years since this answer? Maybe using some `keyof` or type mappings? The latter should be doable I suppose.